# Creating radio button in React using ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Need to create radio buttons for Title (Mr. & Ms.) **using react and the ref attribute**.

**Code for Class(Omitting the useless part)**:-

```
getTitle () {
// how could I get the selected title value here
var title = this.refs. ??;
},

render () {
   return (
       <div className='input-wrap'>
                        <label className='label'>
                            Mr.
                        </label>
                        <input  className='input'
                                type='radio'
                                ref= 'title'
                                name='user_title'
                                value='Mr.'
                                selected />

                        <label className='label'>
                            Ms.
                        </label>
                        <input  className=input'
                                type='radio'
                                ref= 'title'
                                name='user_title'
                                value='Ms.' />
                    </div>

      )
     }
```

**Question:-** *How could I get the selected Title value in getTitl*e() ?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it without `refs`.

```
class Radio extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            inputValue : ''
        }

    }

    change(e){
        const val = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            inputValue : val
        })
    }
    render(){
        return <div>
                <label>MR<input type="radio" name="name" onChange={this.change.bind(this)} value="MR"/></label>
                <label>MS<input type="radio" name="name" onChange={this.change.bind(this)} value="MS"/></label>
                <br/>
                <h2>Value : {this.state.inputValue}</h2>
        </div>
    }
}

React.render(<Radio/>, document.getElementById('container'))
```

***[Fiddle example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/131/)***

I hope it will help you !

Thanks!